# stored procedures instead of forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures

I have a strange question here,

I started working on a website that is already huge. It was built with c# and asp.net. Trying to understand how it works, I got a little confused.

The MVC that i know so far use something like this

```
 <body>
     <form id="form1_ method="create" runat="server">
     .............
     .............
 <asp:button id="btn" onClick="click" ...
```

and inside the controller we handle the "create" verb

but in this website, there is no "form" with methods... just fieldsets and UpdatePanel with a lot o textboxes to be filled ...and when we click the button, the function at the code behind just call a stored procedure, passing the parameters

is it kind of another way to do MVC? I am lost with no HTML verbs to handle

Comment: Are you sure you understand what is ASP.NET Web forms, ASP.NET MVC, stored procedure (which is SQL specific thing, not ASP.NET)? I suggest starting with basic tutorials on these topics and then asking more appropriate question.

Comment: It looks like ASP.NET Web Forms to me.  It's not MVC.

Comment: BTW, there is no "CREATE" method in HTTP.

Comment: i knda agree with some of the comments above. without wishing to come over as cruel, i'd suggest you really step back and get a handle on what defines each of the technologies that you are mis-addressing. you'll do yourself and the client (is there one??) a disservice by moving fwd based on an answer to just this single question

Comment: Sorry about the CREATE.. I mean POST.
I din't know that ASP.Net webforms was different from asp.net mvc. Somehere at internet I saw somebody saying that .net 3.5 has no URL mapping (and I'm using that version). 
I pass parameters like

`/user/user.aspx?action=0`

I am telling the folder, the source code and the value to complete the action, there is no mapping code inside the project doing that (like some restfull webservices)

I will take a look at ASP.NET Web Forms and MVC to understand more about them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're describing [Web Forms](http://www.asp.net/web-forms), which is another part of [ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/), but not part of [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc).

The calling of stored procedures has nothing to do with any of these technologies. Some people choose to put such calls in their Controller or Code-Behind rather than having it in a separate data layer.

Comment: Can I say that using ASP.NET with web forms is not MVC?

Comment: @Mucida: I think you could argue that, yes, since by definition MVC needs a model, view, and controller. If you can't identify which parts of code represent these three parts, then it's not really using MVC. It's definitely not using "ASP.NET MVC."